# Is IP address authentication safe for web service / site?

Tags: web-services, authentication, ip

We're building a web service which users will subscribe to, and we were thinking of authenticating users based on their IP address.

I understand that this creates some hassle, eg, if a client's IP changes, but I wanted to know from a security point of view if this was safe?  I'm not sure how hard it is to spoof IP addresses, but my thinking is that even if that happened we wouldn't end up sending data back to the attacker.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you plan to use IP addresses for authentication? What advantages are you looking for?

Comment: What about NAT? Few users may have the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Think about proxies and  VPN's.
And what if an user would like to use your site from an other PC?

You might want to use browser fingerprints (together with IP) it's safer, but then they must always use the same browser...

Conclusion: not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this would be very risky. Hackers use a number of IP spoofing tools to avoid detection, and there are legitimate anonymity uses. Check out IP onions via the Tor network (used extensively by wikileaks folks, for example) http://www.torproject.org

That said, if your data isn't sensitive AT ALL, like you want to guess their location to show the local weather, you can certainly use IP blocks to roughly locate people. If that kind of thing is all you're after, check out: http://www.hostip.info/dl/index.html